# What is the difference between require() and return in an if() statement?

Tags: solidity

I am reading [this page](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/contracts.html) and trying to understand how these 2 pieces of code will behave:

With `require()`

```
function transfer(address _newOwner) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner)
    // Do the actual transfer
}
```

With `return` in an `if()`:

```
function transfer(address _newOwner) public {
    if (msg.sender != owner) return;
    // Do the actual transfer
}
```

I understand that `require()` will revert all changes and refund me any unused gas, but what exactly does the second code will behave? The function will stop executing, but does it refund unused gas?

Thanks

Comment: The second code will refund unused gas but it will not throw an exception unlike the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second function returns execution to the previous function. So for example if you have something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract Example {

    address owner;
    event SomeEvent();
    event OtherEvent();

    function doSomething(address _someowner) public {
        transfer2(_someowner);
        emit SomeEvent();
        transfer1(_someowner);
        emit OtherEvent();
    }

    function transfer1(address _newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        // Do the actual transfer
    }

    function transfer2(address _newOwner) public {
        if (msg.sender != owner) return;
        // Do the actual transfer
    }
}
```

So what happens if you call `doSomething` with:

1) `_someowner` equals to `owner`:

- `transfer2` performs the transfer
- event `SomeEvent` is emitted
- `transfer1` performs the transfer
- event `OtherEvent` is emitted

2) `_someowner` does not equal to `owner`:

- `transfer2` does not perform the transfer but returns execution to previous function (`doSomething`)
- event `SomeEvent` is emitted
- `transfer1` does not perform the transfer and halts the transaction execution with an error
- event `OtherEvent` is not emitted as the execution never reaches this far

Comment: Thanks, so in other words return from an if() doesn't do any extra stuff (refund gas, halt transaction) other than return the execution flow

Comment: the `if` if not so relevant here - `return` always returns the execution flow if the statement is executed

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60585/what-difference-between-if-and-require-in-solidity/60587) to be helpful.

The answer also has [a link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) to the official docs.